# Merge Git Repos

Tags: git

I have a Repo (called Repo1) and another separate Repo, which has branches in it (REpo2). What I am trying to do is fold changes made in the master branch of Repo2 into Repo1

Is there a way to merge across multiple Repos? or can I only merge between branches of the same Repo?

Comment: unfortunatly the accepted answer on that question requires a third party tool that states that it only works if no merges have been done. my repo has merges so would not work with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can export patches (git diff or git format-patch) and then apply them on the other repo (git apply or git am, or even the plain old "patch" program).

Comment: This is the old-fashioned way of doing things, which is still sometimes valid, but may not be necessary. Github with its pull requests between repositories can be more convenient.

Comment: @RobinGreen: OK, but the OP didn't mention GitHub.  I am also in shock that patch files are now considered by some to be "old fashioned!"

Comment: No , while I use the Github app, I have my remote repos at bitbucket, if I can do it via bitbucket, that would be ok too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a repo-merge, which is a bit complex, but if you google this keywords, you will get much better tutorials on this as I could write right now (I did it for two or three times by now and it always worked *really* good).

Another thing you could do is adding the second repo as remote. Then you are able to merge in the remote branches from this repo.